# OAuth2 authorization interface using KeyCloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to use `KeyCloak` as identity provider service for 3rd party applications support. The idea is to register the client application in `KeyCloak`, trusted clients will not require this authorization approval, but there should be "untrusted" client flow, e.g. display user authorization interface as specified in [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-interface/).

[image: OAuth2 authorization interface]

From what I [see in the docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/authorization_services/topics/overview/architecture.html), they have pretty good fine-grained authorization mechanisms which can be used for that on the backend. However I don't see any way to provide authorization screen for `/authorize` endpoint as shown above.

Maybe this can be [custom created SPI](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/providers.html) or something else which can be used for implementing this to move further. Any ideas of how this can be implemented in `KeyCloak`? Are there any built-in features which can be reused or custom way implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Keycloak* you can turn on the `Consent Required` switch per client (see client settings in admin console).
After successful authentication this will bring up a confirmation page similar to your example.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Boomer If I turn off the consent How to create custom consent page and calling keycloak consent REST api (GET/POST) ?

Comment: @PanupongKongarn Sorry, I don't understand your question. The consent page is an optional step in the OAuth2 authorization flow. In Keycloak you can customize this page by providing a custom theme with a modified file "login-oauth-grant.ftl". But I don't see any point in having a REST API to call the consent page. Perhaps you should open a new question where you can explain more detailed what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Bomer ok thanks I can't found REST API about consent also I will pick up consent table 
from keycloak and do it without keycloak